# When i am logout then i cannot login with same email & password, showing me error jwt

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt

*I can create new account and also i can login but when i am going to logout that time i will logout but if i am try to login with same email and password but i cannot able to login it is showing me jsonwebtoken error -> {"name":"JsonWebTokenError","message":"jwt must be provided"} *
**register.js**
*This is my register.js file code*

```
app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  // res.send('Hello Arunesh')
  res.render("register");
  
});

app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const password = req.body.password;
    const cPassword = req.body.cPassword;
    if (password === cPassword) {
      const registerData = new Register({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        gender: req.body.gender,
        email: req.body.email,
        age: req.body.age,
        password: req.body.password,
        confirmPassword: req.body.cPassword,
      });

      const token = await registerData.generateAuthToken();
      console.log('Register Token : ',token);

      res.cookie('jwt', token,{
        httpOnly:true
      })

      const register = await registerData.save();
      console.log(register);

      res.status(201).render("index");
    } else {
      res.send("Password are not match");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});
```

**login.js**

```
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login");
});

app.post("/login", auth,async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    const userEmail = await Register.findOne({ email: email });

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, userEmail.password);

    const token = await userEmail.generateAuthToken();

    res.cookie('jwt', token,{
      expires:new Date(Date.now()+30000000),
      httpOnly:true
    })

    

    console.log('Login Token : ',token);

    console.log(isMatch);

    if (isMatch) {
      res.status(201).render("index");
    } else {
      res.send("Invalid password or email");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});
```

**Logout.js**

```
app.get('/logout', auth,async (req, res)=>{
  try{
    // console.log(req.user);
    //  Logout for single user
    req.user.tokens = req.user.tokens.filter((authToken)=>{
      return authToken.token != req.token;
    })

    // logout from all device
    // req.user.tokens = [];

    res.clearCookie("jwt");

    await req.user.save();
    res.render('login');
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
})
```

**auth.js**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const Register = require('../models/registers');

const auth = async (req, res, next)=>{

    try{

        const token = req.cookies.jwt;

        const verifyUser = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);

        const user = await Register.findOne({_id:verifyUser._id, 'tokens.token':token})

        req.token = token;
        req.user = user;

        next()
        
    }catch(e){
        res.send(e)
    }

}

module.exports = auth;
```

**
generateAuthToken
**

```
registerSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function () {
  try {
    
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id.toString() },process.env.SECRET_KEY);
    this.tokens = this.tokens.concat({token:token})

    await this.save();

    return token;
    
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

**
Schema
**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const registerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  confirmPassword: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  tokens: [
    {
      token: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ],
});


/********************************************
 *             Generate Token
 ********************************************/
registerSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function () {
  try {
    
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id.toString() },process.env.SECRET_KEY);
    this.tokens = this.tokens.concat({token:token})

    await this.save();

    return token;
    
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

/********************************************
 *             Password Hash
 ********************************************/
registerSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (this.isModified("password")) {
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
    this.confirmPassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
  }

  next();
});

const Register = new mongoose.model("Register", registerSchema);

module.exports = Register;
```

Comment: added your model , show me generateAuthToken

Comment: registerSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function () {
  try {
    
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id.toString() },process.env.SECRET_KEY);
    this.tokens = this.tokens.concat({token:token})

    await this.save();

    return token;
    
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

Comment: added your Schema to your question Completely

Comment: i just added check once

Comment: yes that time it will delete from collection and cookies also

Comment: I spent a lot of time solving the question and answering your question, accepted my answer

Answer (score 0):

you use `auth` middleware in `/login` route, this error happens when the coming token is null or empty ,remove auth middleware from the route like this, I hope the problem is solved with my answer

```
app.post("/login" , async (req, res) => {...
```

Comment: Finally i solve with the your help, Thanks bro 